# Encoding in Java Prograaming Language

Tags: java, encoding

Please see [JLS7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html). Section 3.2 page 16 states

> The Java programming language represents text in sequences of 16-bit code units,
>   using the UTF-16 encoding.

I disassembled a hello world program.

```
class Y {
String hello = "hello";
}
```

Following is the assembly:

```
Classfile /c:/Work/SR1/e2/tmp/Y.class
Last modified Jan 5, 2014; size 240 bytes
MD5 checksum 96694fda4f346a62d5412c56dc36c45d
Compiled from "X.java"
class Y
  SourceFile: "X.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_SUPER
  Constant pool:
  #1 = Class              #2             //  Y
  #2 = Utf8               Y
  #3 = Class              #4             //  java/lang/Object
  #4 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #5 = Utf8               hello
  #6 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/String;
  #7 = Utf8               <init>
  #8 = Utf8               ()V
  #9 = Utf8               Code
  #10 = Methodref          #3.#11         //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #11 = NameAndType        #7:#8          //  "<init>":()V
  #12 = String             #5             //  hello
  #13 = Fieldref           #1.#14         //  Y.hello:Ljava/lang/String;
  #14 = NameAndType        #5:#6          //  hello:Ljava/lang/String;
  #15 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #16 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #17 = Utf8               X.java
  {
  ...
```

I see only Utf8 encoding and no Utf16. Why there is no Utf16 encoding.

Thanks

Comment: Because ... your charset is UTF8. The string *internally* is holding 16bit codepoints.

Comment: type putting some Chinese characters in your string constant and see what it decomplies to

Comment: How do I put 电 in a text file?

Answer (score 5):

In an executing program, text is (typically<sup>1</sup>) represented in UTF-16.

But in a ".class" file, text in the constant pool (i.e. String literals, identifiers, and so on) is encoded in UTF-8 to save space.  (Encoding of constant pool entries in UTF-8 is mandated by the [JVM spec - Section 4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4) ... and is nothing to do with default character sets.)

When the class file is loaded, the UTF-8 constant pool entries are transcoded to UTF-16 by the classloader.

---

<sup>1 - An application could be written to encode text in a myriad different ways.  The UTF-16 encoding we are talking about here is the *natural* encoding scheme for text data in Java; i.e. the encoding you get when you store text a `String` or any other subtype of `CharacterSequence`.</sup>

Comment: There is also no other encoding for a String in the constant pool of a class file: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4

Comment: @Charlie - correct.  (I assume you are referring to Brian Roach's misleading comment ...)

Comment: Yep. Also thought since the question quoted the JLS spec it would be good to provide a link to a relevant portion of the JVM spec.

Comment: Thanks, I've incorporated this.